# adding repetition to calling a function

Tags: c, string, function, repeat

Ok I'm trying to make a code that replaces characters in the string entered with the next ones in the alphabet and and print it 26 times (all letters rotated)
I took help from a rot13 code modified it a little it does EVERYTHING I want except printing it 26 times. I tried to add a counter with both for and while but I really looked stupid and didn't work of course.

here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("Please Enter The Secret Code\n");
    int code;
    while((code = getchar())) {
        code = chariot(code);
        putchar(code);
    } 
    return 0;
}

int chariot(int code)
{
    if('a' <= code && code <= 'z'){
        return Chariot(code,'a');
    } else if ('A' <= code && code <= 'Z') {
       return Chariot(code, 'A');
    } else {
        return code;
    }
}

int Chariot(int code, int newcode){
    code = (((code-newcode)+1)%26)+newcode;
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want, but if you mean something like read in "cat" and then print "dbu", "ecv" .....  "bzs" , you should change the code to read the entire string first, and only then run Chariot function on all its characters in a loop 26 times printing the result after each call.

Comment: what is your input and what output are you expecting ? give us some sample.

Comment: @ShvetChakra I want it to be like this  aAzZ->bBaA->cCbB.......->zZaA   right now i added loop to the function and its working but I cant make it print the code every step it only prints last step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is run this last bit:

```
int Chariot(int code, int new code)
{
    code = (((code-newcode)+1)%26)+newcode;
    return code;
}
```

Through a 'for' loop.

The way it should look would be like this:

```
int Chariot(int code, int new code)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        code = (((code-newcode)+1)%26)+newcode;
    }
    return code;
}
```

What this is doing is running that same bit of code 26 times, which is what your desired result will be. Do some more research on loops as they'll help you out tremendously in your life.

Comment: Thanks man that did the trick now it works 26 times but there is 1 more problem. it made no differance since it doesnt print out every step the output is still same  but thanks anyway I'ld vote up If I could

Comment: If you want it to print out every step, all you would have to do is print inside of the for loop, and it will print 26 times. Try playing around with a snippet like:

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("String %d: %s" i, code);
    }

and see if you can change some things around to get it the way you want. ;)

Comment: tried it but now it stops working when I run and input the string I thşnk this may be because I didnt take string with scanf but i do it with getchar

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on processing the input character by character, you can use this on a sufficiently high VT100 compatible terminal:

```
    while (code = getchar())
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            if (putchar(code = chariot(code)) != '\n') printf("\b\v");
        if (code != '\n') printf(" \e[26A");
    }
```

But of course, this is ridiculous. The sane solution is what o_weisman suggested:

> read the entire string first, and only then run Chariot function on
>   all its characters in a loop 26 times printing the result after each
>   call.